# Excel refreshing formatting

Tags: excel, formatting

I have a column of data that was set to general formatting, I need to change the formatting to text. However each field doesnt update to the text formatting until I double click on each and every cell!

Do any of you know a fast way of fixing this?

I have around 3000 records that needs this update in formatting.

Thanks

Comment: I usually get this problem when I try to change the formatting using the home dropdown menu. I usually work around this using the formatting from Ctrl+1. Could you try that to see if that works or is that what you were doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way

Assume your data are in column A.

1. Insert a blank column between A and B
2. Write a formula in column B2 as follows: =TEXT(A2,"@")
3. You can change the format string I used in step 2 from "@" to anything you wish.  "@" means general formatting.
4. Fill column B down to the bottom
5. Select column B
6. Press ctrl-C (or choose copy from the menu)
7. Choose "Paste Special" and on the dialogue choose "Values"  This essentially freezes the values in column B.
8. Delete column A

Ta da

If you need to do the reverse (change text into general) then use VALUE instead of TEXT.